# Is there a way to set the size of the list window of a ActiveX combobox?

Tags: listview, combobox, activex, dropdown

I Want to set the size of the combobox almost equal to the size of the down arrow, however, when that it is clicked, I want the window that opens to be wide enough to show at least 50 characters. Is there a way to control/set the size of that window with VBA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Why don't you try first? When you get stuck, please post some code and why things are not working the way you think they should.

Comment: I have seen codes that sets the width of the ActiveX combobox in Excel, but I don't know that there is a way to conrol the width of the dropdown window that shows all the list items, indepent of the width of the combobox when it is not clicked on. I could add attach a pic, but I don't have a code to start with.